# Can you create a custom razor view baseclass which has a model and a presentationmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, razor, asp.net-mvc-3

In MVC2 we have a custom base class

```
public class OurViewPage<TModel,TPresentationModel> : ViewPage<TModel>
```

so we have in the view a Model property and a PresentationModel property...

Our Aspx file starts with

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Our.Master"
 Inherits="OurViewPage<IndexModel,IndexPresentationModel>" %>
```

With the MVC3 Razor view engine, would something equivalent be possible?

- from which base class should we inherited.
- how do you specify in the view which classes a view uses (equivalent of the Page directive)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class should derive from `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>`

In your view file you would add the following line to the top:

```
@inherits OurWebViewPage<IndexModel, IndexPresentationModel>
```

Note that you should not use the `@model` syntax if you have a base class with two generic parameters.

Comment: I'm having trouble to add custom namespaces to all my views. I've seen examples using &lt;system.web.webPages.razor&gt; section, but they don't seem to work for me. I want all my models and custom HTML helpers to be known in all views, but I keep getting errors that they are not known and I should add a reference. But I don't want to add @using statements to all my views...

Comment: Ok, found the problem, I added the namespaces to my main web.config, it looks like you should add it to the namespaces of the web.Config inside the Views directory!!